# Displaying multiple images using FlatList component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Am trying to display multiple images using the Flatlist component in react native but i get a TransformError for some reason , i also want each of the images that get displayed to have a diffrent background color that i set.
here is the code i used

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, FlatList } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([
    { name: "creative", id: "1" },
    { name: "traveling", id: "2" },
    { name: "cycling", id: "3" },
    { name: "business", id: "4" },
  ]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={category}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Image source={require(`../../assets/images/${item.name}.png`)} />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

the images files in the assets folder are named exactly the same as the names in item.name

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use require with dynamic params, you should make the require in category const.

```js
const [category, setCategory] = useState([
    { name: "creative", id: "1", source: require('../../assets/images/creative.png') },
    { name: "traveling", id: "2", source: require('../../assets/images/traveling.png') },
  // and so on...
  ]);

// in FlatList

<FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={category}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Image source={item.source} />
        )}
/>
```